# Saving used variables in vector

Tags: rust, borrowing

I want to learn the ownership model of Rust. In the example below I want to `spawn` a `NonCopy` object `child` from the existing `NonCopy` object `eva` and save them in the same vector `population`.

```
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Hash)]
pub struct NonCopy<'a> {
    name: String,
    parent: Option<&'a NonCopy<'a>>,
}

impl<'a> NonCopy<'a> {
    pub fn new(name: String, parent: Option<&'a NonCopy<'a>>) -> Self { // we create a method to instantiate `NonCopy`
        NonCopy { name: name, parent: parent }
    }

    pub fn say_name(&self) -> String {
        format!("{:}", self.name)
    }
}

pub fn spawn<'a>(parent: &'a NonCopy, name: String) -> NonCopy<'a> {
    NonCopy::new(name, Some(parent))
}

fn main() {
    let eva = NonCopy::new(String::from("Eva"), None);
    let child = spawn(&eva, String::from("Son"));
    let mut population = vec![child];
    population.push(eva);
}
```

But when I push `eva` to the vector object `population` I get following error message:

```
   Compiling playground v0.1.0 (/home/holger/git/Rust/playground)
error[E0505]: cannot move out of `eva` because it is borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:25:21
   |
23 |     let child = spawn(&eva, String::from("Son"));
   |                       ---- borrow of `eva` occurs here
24 |     let mut population = vec![child];
25 |     population.push(eva);
   |                ---- ^^^ move out of `eva` occurs here
   |                |
   |                borrow later used by call

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0505`.
error: could not compile `playground`.
```

I would like to ask why it is not possible to `push` `eva` to the same vector as its spawned child `child`.

- `eva` is borrowd to the function `spawn`. According to [Rust By Example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/scope/borrow.html) the borrow should be dropped after the end of `spawn`. Why isn't it dropped?
- Is it because the result of `spawn` is still alive after the end of `spawn`?
- Is this behaviour related to its non `Copy` type?
- How can `eva` and `child` be collected in the same `Vec` object?

Comment: I changed to `let mut population ` and edited the question, but my real problem still occurs.

Comment: I believe your error is caused by the reference `child` holds to `eva`. Because `child` keeps that reference alive ownership of `eva` cannot be passed to the vector.

Comment: @elliptic_hyperboloid That does not seem to be the case. Even if you change `spawn` to not use the borrowed value, the error still persists. ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ef99635be316254fa47a5e84f6bc6e8c)) I think it is more likely that it has to do with the lifetimes, but I don't know enough about it to say for sure.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of the linked question, as the stated error occurs even when the structs have *no* references in them (as shown in the playground linked in my previous comment).

Comment: @Herohtar The lifetime of the returned object has to be different in your playground example. I have created a modified working version ([Playground mod](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=22c8f2f2c37b2c8657115fb1710790a9)).